# How to create a filter queryset on an array so that all search terms are required?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-taggit

I have a `Photo` model with tags. I want to be able to create a query such that only photos having *all* search tag terms will be returned. The current behavior (using the view code below) returns photos having *any* of the tags being searched on.

```
@list_route(methods=['post'])
def tags(self, request):
    """
    search for entities by tags they contain
    :param request:
    :return: Response
    """
    tags = json.loads(request.data['tags'])
    photos = Photo.objects.filter(tags__name__in=tags, owner=self.request.user).distinct()
    page = self.paginate_queryset(photos)
    if page is not None:
        serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
        return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)

    serializer = self.get_serializer(photos, many=True)
    return Response(
        data=serializer.data
    )
```

Here is the model class:

```
class Photo(TimestampModerated):
    owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='photos', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    uuid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid4, editable=False)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=80, editable=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=80, blank=False, null=False)
    description = models.TextField(verbose_name='description of entity', blank=True, null=True)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to=user_directory_path, height_field="height", width_field="width", blank=True)
    height = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    width = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    tags = TaggableManager(blank=True)
    hash = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "photos"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def delete(self, using=None, keep_parents=False):
        default_storage.delete("{}".format(self.photo))
        super().delete()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super(Photo, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I'm using `django-rest-framework` to create the views and `django-taggit` for the tagging.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to loop over the list of terms adding `filter` terms:

```
photos = Photos.objects.filter(owner=self.request.user)
for tag in tags:
    photos = photos.filter(tags__name=tag)
photos = photos.distinct()
```

Combining `Q` objects is not suitable here, because as the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#spanning-multi-valued-relationships) explain Django requires all constraints in a single `filter` clause to be met by the same related object - `AND`ing together multiple `Q` objects would require that one tag have a name equal to each term in the list.

Comment: Ah I didn't realize you could do that. That seems like the simplest solution for now.

Comment: @EvanZamir Also you can use `Q()` objects to achieve `AND` semantics.

Comment: @SergeyZherevchuk Thanks, I don't know much about `Q()` until now but I will do some more research. Are there any performance advantages to one or the other of these approaches?

Comment: No, it will generate the same sql (with & operator, of course). FYI: You can debug your resulting SQL with `print(queryset.query)` statement or install `django-debug-toolbar` for this purpose.

Comment: The `Q()` syntax works fine too, and you'll need it if you want to `OR` together multiple filters that can't be expressed with an `in` query. The most idiomatic way to combine multiple filters using `Q()` when the list of tags is of unknown length is using `reduce`, which can be a little harder to read if you're not used to it. So it's just a question of preference.

Comment: I tried using `Q()` and it doesn't seem to work for me. Peter, if you would be kind enough to add some code to your answer demonstrating how it would look, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hmm, actually, `Q()` objects aren't too bad since you can pass multiple ones to the call and they'll be `AND`ed together. `reduce` is only really necessary for for `OR` semantics. I'll update.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper tried exactly the code you suggested for Q, but when I use multiple tags, nothing is returned.

Comment: Your model uses `tags` rather than `tag`, but if that were the problem you'd probably get an exception. I can't really debug remotely, maybe compare the SQL for the successive `.filter()` version to that from the `*(Q...)` version as suggested above.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper I've put the two generated queries in a gist. If you have time, feel free to take a look! They're not the same. The first method seems to have an extra join in there. https://gist.github.com/EvanZ/ed96e1c2bd09c1122f65e534fd479f81

Comment: Oh right, that's the expected behavior: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#spanning-multi-valued-relationships - so the multiple Q objects approach just doesn't work, it's telling Django to look for a tag whose name equals "foo" and equals "bar". It would be useful if you were doing, say, a `__contains` query or querying on different fields of a tag or something, but to find images with the multiple tags you probably do need just the successive `filter()` calls.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper Makes sense!